# unable to complete batchupdate based on JSON payload object

Tags: c#, api, google-sheets

I am just trying to format a google sheet cell range to number format using c# and using the google sheets api v4. This is how the JSON object is structured:

in C#, this is set to a string.
Yet this is not a valid parameter for the following command:
myService.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate(strPayload, strSpreadSheetID);
Based on the parameter reference, the 1'st parameter required is BatchUpdateSpreadSheetRequest object, yet documentation how to incorporate the JSON payload object into the BatchUpdateSpreadSheetRequest object is leaving me spinning in circles.

What steps am I missing ?

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "repeatCell": {
        "range": {
          "sheetId": sheetId,
          "startRowIndex": 0,
          "endRowIndex": 10,
          "startColumnIndex": 1,
          "endColumnIndex": 2
        },
        "cell": {
          "userEnteredFormat": {
            "numberFormat": {
              "type": "NUMBER",
              "pattern": "#,##0.0000"
            }
          }
        },
        "fields": "userEnteredFormat.numberFormat"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

need to get the proper structure of the request object for the batchupdate to compile and execute.

Comment: for clarification, I use stringbuilder to build the properly JSON payload object. I then convert to string and pass that result to SpreadSheets.BatchUpdate(strJSONObject,<spreadsheetID>);

Comment: How are you getting on with your Google Sheets problem? Have you resolved it, or are you still looking for help?